# XPath run text() through regular expression to return numbers only

Tags: python, regex, xpath

I have been experimenting with XPath, am pretty new with it, I did a parser that would extract text() from element in one of the nodes.

I wrote the below

```
 xhtml = etree.HTML(i.get('content').encode('utf8'))
 result = etree.tostring(xhtml, pretty_print=True, method="html")
 root = html.fromstring(result)
 print root.xpath('//td[contains(text(), "Shipment Total:")]/following-sibling::td/b/text()')
```

the above is returning

```
[' $25.79 ']
```

Is there a way, using XPath only to trim the spaces and return only the number to escape the dollar sign? I read about fn::match in XPath but i couldn't figure it out. Anyone can help with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

per xpath specs ([here](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-substring-after) and [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-normalize-space)),

```
print root.xpath('substring-after(normalize-space(//td[contains(text(), "Shipment Total:")]/following-sibling::td/b/text()), "$")')
```

should do the trick.

for more complex extractions you may have to resort to [`fn:replace`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2010/REC-xpath-functions-20101214/#func-replace) indeed. note however that this requires a processor supporting xpath 2.0.